# Strange leak in the AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, instruments

Why does Instruments detect a leak in the following lines of code in the `AppDelegate` class? Here is a screenshot from the "leaks" instrument, and below is source code.

[image: Instruments Screenshot]

`AppDelegate` implementation file:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Strings.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize window = hWindow;
- (void)dealloc
{
    [hWindow release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
   // [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {    // The iOS device = iPhone or iPod Touch

        CGSize iOSDeviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        UIViewController *initialViewController = nil;
        if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 480)
        {   // iPhone 3GS, 4, and 4S and iPod Touch 3rd and 4th generation: 3.5 inch screen (diagonally measured)

            // Instantiate a new storyboard object using the storyboard file named Storyboard_iPhone35
            UIStoryboard *iPhone35Storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard_Retina3.5" bundle:nil];

            // Instantiate the initial view controller object from the storyboard
            initialViewController = [iPhone35Storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
        }

        if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 568)
        {   // iPhone 5 and iPod Touch 5th generation: 4 inch screen (diagonally measured)

            // Instantiate a new storyboard object using the storyboard file named Storyboard_iPhone4
            UIStoryboard *iPhone4Storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];

            // Instantiate the initial view controller object from the storyboard
            initialViewController = [iPhone4Storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
        }
        // Instantiate a UIWindow object and initialize it with the screen size of the iOS device
        [self setWindow:[[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease]];

        // Set the initial view controller to be the root view controller of the window object
        self.window.rootViewController  = initialViewController;

        // Set the window object to be the key window and show it

    } else if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {   // The iOS device = iPad
        UIViewController *initialViewController = nil;
        UIStoryboard *iPhone4Storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:nil];

        // Instantiate the initial view controller object from the storyboard
        initialViewController = [iPhone4Storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
        [self setWindow:[[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease]];

        // Set the initial view controller to be the root view controller of the window object
        self.window.rootViewController  = initialViewController;
        // Set the window object to be the key window and show it

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
    }
    [[self window] makeKeyAndVisible];
    NSLog(@"%d",[[self window] retainCount]);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < 70000
    //iOS 7 only stuff here
#endif
    return YES;
}
.....
@end
```

`AppDelegate` header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    UIWindow *hWindow;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

May the reason for this be that the app is still running and not terminated in order to deallocate? I would like to mention that in Xcode 4 I was not getting such a leak, it started to appear in Xcode 5.

Answer (score 3):

The leaks tool is only telling you the line of code that caused the leak to be allocated and *not* why it was leaked.   In this case, since it is a run-once method and, assumedly, it is a single object designed to stick around for the lifetime of your app, it isn't a problem.

It is, however, something you should fix, but there isn't enough information here to suggest a fix.

What object(s) is(are) claimed to be leaked?

Also, it is atypical to do things like `@synthesize window = hWindow`.  Don't declare the ivar and just let the compiler automatically synthesize `_window`.  This will result in code much closer to standard pattern.

Comment: So what you are suggesting is that the object(s) which are responsible for the leak are in my controller class and the `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];` line is just where it starts?

Comment: @axel Exactly.   That `makeKeyAndVisible` likely causes a bunch of stuff to be allocated as a side effect of putting stuff on screen.